# Preview and Safari show images at double size

Tags: display, safari, preview

When I open images in Safari or Preview, then view them at actual size, they are shown at twice size. I want them to show at *actually* actual size -- that is, where 1 pixel in an image corresponds to 1 pixel of the display.

Let me illustrate my point. My monitor is 3840 × 2160px. I made an image image with those same dimensions, then opened it fullscreen in Preview.

Here is the image:
[image]

Next, I open it in Preview. This defaults to the "Zoom to Fit." Notice how there is one teeny, tiny red pixel. It is shown as 1 pixel on my monitor:
[image]

After selecting "Actual Size" in Preview this is what I see. The image is shown at double size. The one red pixel is now 2 × 2px:
[image]

Here is where it gets interesting. Within Preview, if I change the resolution of the image from 72 to 144 pixels/inch then the image displays in the way I want.

*How do I make Preview, Safari, and other parts of macOS display images at 1:1 without changing the resolution of every image?*

Update 1:
In Preview, pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> shows the image as the correct 3840 × 2160px size.
[image]

Comment: What does "file" report? And/or the Info tab in Prefix for the file?

Comment: Perhaps it's todo with display resolution ... My laptop when I use Cmd-Shift-4 gives a screen res of 1280x800px - whereas About This MAC -> Displays gives 2304x1440px - so maybe there's the source of the difference?

Comment: @MrR I think what you are noticing is points vs pixels. When I do the same I get 1920 × 1080 (points), because macOS is rendering at 2× on my screen. I'm guessing you have selected a scaled resolution from System Preferences.

Comment: Nope - on mine it's "Default for Display" ..  Older OSX let you pick pixel resolution.   I think that's what you are seeing..  Note: 72dpi is the "standard" monitor resolution that many designers work to - of course the correct display resolution DOES depend on the size monitor it can be displayed on - because tools (like the adobe tools) choose the amount of anti-aliasing to do based on that..